# XPAGES - add a file in a rich text with getDocumentByUNID

Tags: java, file, xpages, lotus-domino

I try to create a pdf with itext and adding this in a rich text.
I create the pdf it's ok but when i want to put the file in the rich text, i have an error : "null" in my document Notes.

I don't understand.

This is my code :

```
// recupere l'id du document ouvert dans l'url
            String idDocument = XSPContext.getXSPContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance())
                    .getUrl().getParameter("documentId");

            // recupere le document
            Session session = Factory.fromLotus(Utils.getSession(), Session.class, null);
            Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
            Document docRepeat = db.getDocumentByUNID(idDocument);

pieceJointe.copieFichierDansRichText(docRepeat, nomChampSauvegarderPdf, tempDocPdf,
                    nomPdf, REPERTOIRE);
```

I create my pdf'file (it's ok) and =>

```
public void copieFichierDansRichText(Document monDoc, String nomRti, File file,
        String nameFichier, String chemin) {  RichTextItem rtiNew = (RichTextItem) monDoc.createRichTextItem(nomRti);
    PieceJointe pieceJointe = new PieceJointe();
    pieceJointe = buildPieceJointe(file, nameFichier, chemin);

    rtiNew.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, null, pieceJointe.getChemin(),
            pieceJointe.getNomPiece());
    monDoc.computeWithForm(true, false);
    monDoc.save();}
```

The problem i have

[image]

But when i use this to create my pdf it's ok i have the informations ????
it's only when i want to create the rich text that it says null exception !
In the console i have "org.openntf.domino.utils.DominoUtils$4 run"
Could you help me ?

**EDIT** 
it seems that docRepeat is the problem

```
Document docRepeat = db.getDocumentByUNID(idDocument);
```

I try docRepeat is not null, there is an exception toArray....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find !
It's openntf which don't works.
I must use lotus.domino.document =>

```
public void copieFichierDansRichText(String idDocument, String nomRti, File file,
        String nameFichier, String chemin) throws NotesException {

    lotus.domino.Session session = Utils.getSession();
    lotus.domino.Database db = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    lotus.domino.Document monDoc = db.getDocumentByUNID(idDocument);

    try {
        if (monDoc != null) {
            lotus.domino.RichTextItem rtiNew = (lotus.domino.RichTextItem) monDoc
                    .getFirstItem(nomRti);
            PieceJointe pieceJointe = new PieceJointe();
            pieceJointe = buildPieceJointe(file, nameFichier, chemin);

            rtiNew.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", pieceJointe.getChemin()
                    + pieceJointe.getNomPiece(), pieceJointe.getNomPiece());
            monDoc.computeWithForm(true, true);
            monDoc.save(true);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call recycle() on your domino objects when using the lotus API

Comment: yes i will add this Thanks rtiNew.recycle(); monDoc.recycle(); db.recycle(); but for the session i do or not ?

Comment: I recycle session also. I've seen conflicting information on if it is needed or not so to be safe I recycle session when I no longer need it.